# How to prevent loosing a button click event when an input element change event occurs in javascript?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, happening

I have a form that contains several input elements of different types, including an input text element with a change event handler assigned to the onchange property.  There is also a button with a click event handler assigned to its onclick property.

With the focus in the input text element with the change event handler and a value is entered into the field or the existing value in the field is changed, then I click on the button, the input text element fires its change event, but the button doesn't seem to fire its click event.  If the field is empty or the value isn't changed, then clicking on the button does cause its click event to fire.

I've put breakpoints in the fieldChange and buttonClick event handler functions, but only the fieldChange function stops at the breakpoint in the first case, above.

I am using the current version of Chrome.

**How do I get both events to fire?**

Here is a summary of my page:

```
<form ...>
  ⫶
  <input type="text" ... onchange="fieldChange( this );" />
  ⫶
  <button id="submitButton" ... onclick="buttonClick( this );">Login</button>
  ⫶
  <script>
    function fieldChange( This ) {
      //
      // If This.value is not empty, then a div containing only text is hidden,
      // otherwise, nothing happens.
      // 
      ⫶   // Code not shown: consists of a test on This.value and hiding a div.
      //
      // This function doesn't have a return statement nor does it cancel/prevent
      // the event from propagating in any way.
      //
    }

    function buttonClick( This ) {
      //
      // This button collects data from the form and does an Ajax call.
      //

      var data = new FormData( $( This ).closest( 'form' )[ 0 ] );
      $.ajax( { type: 'POST', data: data, cache: false, async: true,
                contentType: false, enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                processData: false } )
      .done( function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) { ... } );

      return false; // Stop the form from submitting ...
    }
  </script>
</form>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: I think the button click is first firing the change handler normally, which is blocking the latter. That may not be obvious (the change handler fires when focus goes from the input to the button).

Comment: Jared, Thanks, but wouldn't a breakpoint placed at the first executable line of the click handler function show that it was actually firing?  Also, the Ajax call, performed would have displayed that there were missing values in some of the fields -- but this isn't happening, either

Comment: Scott, Thanks, but no console message occurs when this happens.